# efficiently checking that all the elements of a (big) list are the same

Tags: list, haskell

### Problem

Let us suppose that we have a list `xs` (possibly a very big one), and we want to check that all its elements are the same.

I came up with various ideas:

### Solution 0

checking that all elements in `tail xs` are equal to `head xs`:

```
allTheSame :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allTheSame xs = and $ map (== head xs) (tail xs)
```

### Solution 1

checking that `length xs` is equal to the length of the list obtained by taking elements from `xs` while they're equal to `head xs`

```
allTheSame' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allTheSame' xs = (length xs) == (length $ takeWhile (== head xs) xs)
```

### Solution 2

recursive solution: `allTheSame` returns `True` if the first two elements of `xs` are equal and `allTheSame` returns `True` on the rest of `xs`

```
allTheSame'' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allTheSame'' xs
  | n == 0 = False
  | n == 1 = True
  | n == 2 = xs !! 0 == xs !! 1
  | otherwise = (xs !! 0 == xs !! 1) && (allTheSame'' $ snd $ splitAt 2 xs)
    where  n = length xs
```

### Solution 3

divide and conquer:

```
allTheSame''' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allTheSame''' xs
  | n == 0 = False
  | n == 1 = True
  | n == 2 = xs !! 0 == xs !! 1
  | n == 3 = xs !! 0 == xs !! 1 && xs !! 1 == xs !! 2
  | otherwise = allTheSame''' (fst split) && allTheSame''' (snd split)
    where n = length xs
          split = splitAt (n `div` 2) xs
```

### Solution 4

I just thought about this while writing this question:

```
allTheSame'''' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allTheSame'''' xs = all (== head xs) (tail xs)
```

### Questions

1. I think Solution 0 is not very efficient, at least in terms of memory, because `map` will construct another list before applying `and` to its elements. Am I right?
2. Solution 1 is still not very efficient, at least in terms of memory, because `takeWhile` will again build an additional list. Am I right?
3. Solution 2 is tail recursive (right?), and it should be pretty efficient, because it will return `False` as soon as `(xs !! 0 == xs !! 1)` is False. Am I right?
4. Solution 3 should be the best one, because it complexity should be O(log n)
5. Solution 4 looks quite Haskellish to me (is it?), but it's probably the same as Solution 0, because `all p =  and . map p` (from Prelude.hs). Am I right?
6. Are there other better ways of writing `allTheSame`? Now, I expect someone will answer this question telling me that there's a build-in function that does this: I've searched with hoogle and I haven't found it. Anyway, since I'm learning Haskell, I believe that this was a good exercise for me :)

Any other comment is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: You seem to not be aware of the complexities of some of the operations you're performing: `length` is `O(n)` so you should really prefer pattern matching on the list over taking the length. Further it should be noted that indexing into a list at index `i` is `O(i)` and splitting a list in two is again `O(n)`. (If all of those where `O(1)`, your divide and conquer solution would still not have logarithmic runtime - it would be `O(n log n)`).

Comment: @sepp2k `O(n*log(n))` is its current complexity. Given efficient `length` and `splitAt` it would run in `O(n)`. However, it is just wrong. I think it returns `True` for `[1,1,2,2]`.

Comment: Note that `and . map` is the definition of `all`, making 0 and 4 equivalent. [Source](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#all)

Comment: @sepp2k: good point! I should use pattern matching. However I don't understand your final remark. Given that `splitAt` is O(n), then I understand that my Solution 3 is O(n lg n) (the depth of the tree is lg n, and at every level splitting is O(n)). However, why do you say it's O(n lg n) even if `splitAt` was O(1)?

Comment: @Rotsor: you're right: both my Solution 2 and Solution 3 fail on `[1,1,2,2]`. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: @Dan: yes, I've noticed the equivalence of 0 and 4. Thanks.

Comment: For Solution 0, you probably want to use pattern matching instead of `head` and `tail`.

Comment: Pattern matching, as per @PyRulez, would look like:

`same(eq:eqs) = all (== eq) eqs`
If you want to handle the case of an empty list, you can add `same[]=True`.

Comment: Is this going too far? `allTheSame = all . (==) <$> head <*> tail`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

gatoatigrado's answer gives some nice advice for measuring the performance of various solutions. Here is a more symbolic answer.

I think solution 0 (or, *exactly equivalently*, solution 4) will be the fastest.  Remember that Haskell is *lazy*, so `map` will not have to construct the whole list before `and` is applied.  A good way to build intuition about this is to play with infinity.  So for example:

```
ghci> and $ map (< 1000) [1..]
False
```

This asks whether all numbers are less than 1,000.  If `map` constructed the entire list before `and` were applied, then this question could never be answered.  The expression will still answer quickly even if you give the list a very large right endpoint (that is, Haskell is not doing any "magic" depending on whether a list is infinite).

To start my example, let's use these definitions:

```
and [] = True
and (x:xs) = x && and xs

map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs

True && x = x
False && x = False
```

Here is the evaluation order for `allTheSame [7,7,7,7,8,7,7,7]`.  There will be extra sharing that is too much of a pain to write down.  I will also evaluate the `head` expression earlier than it would be for conciseness (it would have been evaluated anyway, so it's hardly different).

```
allTheSame [7,7,7,7,8,7,7,7]
allTheSame (7:7:7:7:8:7:7:7:[])
and $ map (== head (7:7:7:7:8:7:7:7:[])) (tail (7:7:7:7:8:7:7:7:[]))
and $ map (== 7)  (tail (7:7:7:7:8:7:7:7:[]))
and $ map (== 7)          (7:7:7:8:7:7:7:[])
and $ (== 7) 7 : map (== 7) (7:7:8:7:7:7:[])
(== 7) 7 && and (map (== 7) (7:7:8:7:7:7:[]))
True     && and (map (== 7) (7:7:8:7:7:7:[]))
            and (map (== 7) (7:7:8:7:7:7:[]))
(== 7) 7 && and (map (== 7)   (7:8:7:7:7:[]))
True     && and (map (== 7)   (7:8:7:7:7:[]))
            and (map (== 7)   (7:8:7:7:7:[]))
(== 7) 7 && and (map (== 7)     (8:7:7:7:[]))
True     && and (map (== 7)     (8:7:7:7:[]))
            and (map (== 7)     (8:7:7:7:[]))
(== 7) 8 && and (map (== 7)       (7:7:7:[]))
False    && and (map (== 7)       (7:7:7:[]))
False
```

See how we didn't even have to check the last 3 7's?  This is lazy evaluation making a list work more like a loop.  All your other solutions use expensive functions like `length` (which have to walk all the way to the end of the list to give an answer), so they will be less efficient and also they will not work on infinite lists.  Working on infinite lists and being efficient often go together in Haskell.

Comment: I'm glad that you wrote this answer.  After I finished mine I thought that a manual evaluation would be useful but didn't want to get even longer.  Although I don't think it's sensible to use any variant of `allTheSame` on an infinite list...

Comment: Yeah, it only terminates when the answer is `False` ;-).

Comment: great! thank you for taking the time for writing the example: it has been really helpful for me to understand how lazy evaluation works, and I have to keep this in mind for the future :)

Comment: Even if it's python and it's a regular array (python confusingly calls it a list, though), I won't even think about divide and conquer.

Answer (score 23):

First of all, I don't think you want to be working with lists.  A lot of your algorithms rely upon calculating the length, which is bad.  You may want to consider the [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) package, which will give you O(1) length compared to O(n) for a list.  Vectors are also much more memory efficient, particularly if you can use Unboxed or Storable variants.

That being said, you really need to consider traversals and usage patterns in your code.  Haskell's lists are very efficient if they can be generated on demand and consumed once.  This means that you shouldn't hold on to references to a list.  Something like this:

```
average xs = sum xs / length xs
```

requires that the entire list be retained in memory (by either `sum` or `length`) until both traversals are completed.  If you can do your list traversal in one step, it'll be much more efficient.

Of course, you may need to retain the list anyway, such as to check if all the elements are equal, and if they aren't, do something else with the data.  In this case, with lists of any size you're probably better off with a more compact data structure (e.g. vector).

Now that this is out of they way, here's a look at each of these functions.  Where I show core, it was generated with `ghc-7.0.3 -O -ddump-simpl`.  Also, don't bother judging Haskell code performance when compiled with -O0.  Compile it with the flags you would actually use for production code, typically at least -O and maybe other options too.

**Solution 0**

```
allTheSame :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allTheSame xs = and $ map (== head xs) (tail xs)
```

GHC produces this Core:

```
Test.allTheSame
  :: forall a_abG. GHC.Classes.Eq a_abG => [a_abG] -> GHC.Bool.Bool
[GblId,
 Arity=2,
 Str=DmdType LS,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=2, Value=True,
         ConLike=True, Cheap=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=IF_ARGS [3 3] 16 0}]
Test.allTheSame =
  \ (@ a_awM)
    ($dEq_awN :: GHC.Classes.Eq a_awM)
    (xs_abH :: [a_awM]) ->
    case xs_abH of _ {
      [] ->
        GHC.List.tail1
        `cast` (CoUnsafe (forall a1_axH. [a1_axH]) GHC.Bool.Bool
                :: (forall a1_axH. [a1_axH]) ~ GHC.Bool.Bool);
      : ds1_axJ xs1_axK ->
        letrec {
          go_sDv [Occ=LoopBreaker] :: [a_awM] -> GHC.Bool.Bool
          [LclId, Arity=1, Str=DmdType S]
          go_sDv =
            \ (ds_azk :: [a_awM]) ->
              case ds_azk of _ {
                [] -> GHC.Bool.True;
                : y_azp ys_azq ->
                  case GHC.Classes.== @ a_awM $dEq_awN y_azp ds1_axJ of _ {
                    GHC.Bool.False -> GHC.Bool.False; GHC.Bool.True -> go_sDv ys_azq
                  }
              }; } in
        go_sDv xs1_axK
    }
```

This looks pretty good, actually.  It will produce an error with an empty list, but that's easily fixed.  This is the `case xs_abH of _ { [] ->`.  After this GHC performed a worker/wrapper transformation, the recursive worker function is the `letrec { go_sDv` binding.  The worker examines its argument.  If `[]`, it's reached the end of the list and returns True.  Otherwise it compares the head of the remaining to the first element and either returns False or checks the rest of the list.

Three other features.

1. The `map` was entirely fused away
   and doesn't allocate a temporary
   list.
2. Near the top of the definition
   notice the `Cheap=True` statement. 
   This means GHC considers the
   function "cheap", and thus a
   candidate for inlining.  At a call
   site, if a concrete argument type
   can be determined, GHC will probably
   inline `allTheSame` and produce a
   very tight inner loop, completely
   bypassing the `Eq` dictionary
   lookup.
3. The worker function is
   tail-recursive.

Verdict: Very strong contender.

**Solution 1**

```
allTheSame' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allTheSame' xs = (length xs) == (length $ takeWhile (== head xs) xs)
```

Even without looking at core I know this won't be as good.  The list is traversed more than once, first by `length xs` then by `length $ takeWhile`.  Not only do you have the extra overhead of multiple traversals, it means that the list must be retained in memory after the first traversal and can't be GC'd.  For a big list, this is a serious problem.

```
Test.allTheSame'
  :: forall a_abF. GHC.Classes.Eq a_abF => [a_abF] -> GHC.Bool.Bool
[GblId,
 Arity=2,
 Str=DmdType LS,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=2, Value=True,
         ConLike=True, Cheap=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=IF_ARGS [3 3] 20 0}]
Test.allTheSame' =
  \ (@ a_awF)
    ($dEq_awG :: GHC.Classes.Eq a_awF)
    (xs_abI :: [a_awF]) ->
    case GHC.List.$wlen @ a_awF xs_abI 0 of ww_aC6 { __DEFAULT ->
    case GHC.List.$wlen
           @ a_awF
           (GHC.List.takeWhile
              @ a_awF
              (let {
                 ds_sDq :: a_awF
                 [LclId, Str=DmdType]
                 ds_sDq =
                   case xs_abI of _ {
                     [] -> GHC.List.badHead @ a_awF; : x_axk ds1_axl -> x_axk
                   } } in
               \ (ds1_dxa :: a_awF) ->
                 GHC.Classes.== @ a_awF $dEq_awG ds1_dxa ds_sDq)
              xs_abI)
           0
    of ww1_XCn { __DEFAULT ->
    GHC.Prim.==# ww_aC6 ww1_XCn
    }
    }
```

Looking at the core doesn't tell much beyond that.  However, note these lines:

```
case GHC.List.$wlen @ a_awF xs_abI 0 of ww_aC6 { __DEFAULT ->
        case GHC.List.$wlen
```

This is where the list traversals happen.  The first gets the length of the outer list and binds it to `ww_aC6`.  The second gets the length of the inner list, but the binding doesn't happen until near the bottom, at

```
of ww1_XCn { __DEFAULT ->
GHC.Prim.==# ww_aC6 ww1_XCn
```

The lengths (both `Int`s) can be unboxed and compared by a primop, but that's a small consolation after the overhead that's been introduced.

Verdict: Not good.

**Solution 2**

```
allTheSame'' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allTheSame'' xs
  | n == 0 = False
  | n == 1 = True
  | n == 2 = xs !! 0 == xs !! 1
  | otherwise = (xs !! 0 == xs !! 1) && (allTheSame'' $ snd $ splitAt 2 xs)
    where  n = length xs
```

This has the same problem as solution 1.  The list is traversed multiple times, and it can't be GC'd.  It's worse here though, because now the length is calculated for each sub-list.  I'd expect this to have the worst performance of all on lists of any significant size.  Also, why are you special-casing lists of 1 and 2 elements when you're expecting the list to be big?

Verdict: Don't even think about it.

**Solution 3**

```
allTheSame''' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allTheSame''' xs
  | n == 0 = False
  | n == 1 = True
  | n == 2 = xs !! 0 == xs !! 1
  | n == 3 = xs !! 0 == xs !! 1 && xs !! 1 == xs !! 2
  | otherwise = allTheSame''' (fst split) && allTheSame''' (snd split)
    where n = length xs
          split = splitAt (n `div` 2) xs
```

This has the same problem as Solution 2.  Namely, the list is traversed multiple times by `length`.  I'm not certain a divide-and-conquer approach is a good choice for this problem, it could end up taking longer than a simple scan.  It would depend on the data though, and be worth testing.

Verdict: Maybe, if you used a different data structure.

**Solution 4**

```
allTheSame'''' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allTheSame'''' xs = all (== head xs) (tail xs)
```

This was basically my first thought.  Let's check the core again.

```
Test.allTheSame''''
  :: forall a_abC. GHC.Classes.Eq a_abC => [a_abC] -> GHC.Bool.Bool
[GblId,
 Arity=2,
 Str=DmdType LS,
 Unf=Unf{Src=<vanilla>, TopLvl=True, Arity=2, Value=True,
         ConLike=True, Cheap=True, Expandable=True,
         Guidance=IF_ARGS [3 3] 10 0}]
Test.allTheSame'''' =
  \ (@ a_am5)
    ($dEq_am6 :: GHC.Classes.Eq a_am5)
    (xs_alK :: [a_am5]) ->
    case xs_alK of _ {
      [] ->
        GHC.List.tail1
        `cast` (CoUnsafe (forall a1_axH. [a1_axH]) GHC.Bool.Bool
                :: (forall a1_axH. [a1_axH]) ~ GHC.Bool.Bool);
      : ds1_axJ xs1_axK ->
        GHC.List.all
          @ a_am5
          (\ (ds_dwU :: a_am5) ->
             GHC.Classes.== @ a_am5 $dEq_am6 ds_dwU ds1_axJ)
          xs1_axK
    }
```

Ok, not too bad.  Like solution 1, this will error on empty lists.  The list traversal is hidden in `GHC.List.all`, but it will probably be expanded to good code at a call site.

Verdict: Another strong contender.

So between all of these, with lists I'd expect that Solutions 0 and 4 are the only ones worth using, and they are pretty much the same.  I might consider Option 3 in some cases.

Edit: in both cases, the errors on empty lists can be simply fixed as in @augustss's answer.

The next step would be to do some time profiling with [criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion).

Comment: wow! impressive answer. I must admit that I don't understand anything looking at core code: that's far too advanced for me at the moment. However your explanations are very useful, and they gave me insight on many aspects and errors in my code. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure about the comment about vector which I find incorrect (especially for big list) and slightly patronising and above all unnecessary and not related to the question.

Answer (score 12):

A solution using consecutive pairs:

```
allTheSame xs = and $ zipWith (==) xs (tail xs)
```

Comment: I suggest `drop 1` instead of `tail` so it will work for empty lists as well.

Comment: @dfeuer, actually it works with empty lists, in that case it's not evaluated (because `zipWith` stops before).

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. Sorry. `tail` is still a bit confusing, I think.

Comment: Pointfree: `allTheSame = and . (zipWith (==) <*> tail)`

Comment: How does this compare with original Solution 0 in terms of performance? Assuming to add check for empty list.

Answer (score 6):

Q1 -- Yeah, I think your simple solution is fine, there is no memory leak. Q4 -- Solution 3 is not log(n), via the very simple argument that you need to look at all list elements to determine whether they are the same, and looking at 1 element takes 1 time step. Q5 -- yes. Q6, see below.

The way to go about this is to type it in and run it

```
main = do
    print $ allTheSame (replicate 100000000 1)
```

then run `ghc -O3 -optc-O3 --make Main.hs && time ./Main`. I like the last solution best (you can also use pattern matching to clean it up a little),

```
allTheSame (x:xs) = all (==x) xs
```

Open up ghci and run ":step fcn" on these things. It will teach you a lot about what lazy evaluation is expanding. In general, when you match a constructor, e.g. "x:xs", that's constant time. When you call "length", Haskell needs to compute all of the elements in the list (though their values are still "to-be-computed"), so solution 1 and 2 are bad.

#### edit 1

Sorry if my previous answer was a bit shallow. It seems like expanding things manually does help a little (though compared to the other options, it's a trivial improvement),

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
allTheSame [] = True
allTheSame ((!x):xs) = go x xs where
    go !x [] = True
    go !x (!y:ys) = (x == y) && (go x ys)
```

It seems that ghc is specializing the function already, but you can look at the specialize pragma too, in case it doesn't work for your code [ [link](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#specialize-pragma) ].

Comment: Inserting strict matching changes the semantics of the original function.

Comment: Thank you for all the great comments! I like very your suggestion to clean up my last solution using pattern matching. Thank you also for suggesting :step ... but I still have to learn about gchi debugger: could you recommend a good tutorial?

Comment: I didn't really use a tutorial, just start it up (ghci) and poke it, e.g. "let f = ...", "1+2", etc. Then, you can load files with ":l filename" or start ghci with "ghci Filename.hs". Also, I use ":r" to reload the file constantly. Type :help for a list of commands -- you should see ":step <expr>                single-step into <expr>". cheers.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another version (don't need to traverse whole list in case something doesn't match):

```
allTheSame [] = True
allTheSame (x:xs) = isNothing $ find (x /= ) xs
```

This may not be syntactically correct , but I hope you got the idea.

Comment: Solutions 0 and 4 also don't traverse the whole list if a mismatch is found.

Comment: `isNothing` can be used to make it shorter.

Comment: great alternative idea that also teaches me about `isNothing` and `find`, which I didn't know. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here's another fun way:

```
{-# INLINABLE allSame #-}
allSame :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
allSame xs = foldr go (`seq` True) xs Nothing where
  go x r Nothing = r (Just x)
  go x r (Just prev) = x == prev && r (Just x)
```

By keeping track of the previous element, rather than the first one, this implementation can easily be changed to implement `increasing` or `decreasing`. To check all of them against the first instead, you could rename `prev` to `first`, and replace `Just x` with `Just first`.

---

How will this be optimized? I haven't checked in detail, but I'm going to tell a good story based on some things I know about GHC's optimizations.

Suppose first that list fusion does not occur. Then `foldr` will be inlined, giving something like

```
allSame xs = allSame' xs Nothing where
  allSame' [] = (`seq` True)
  allSame' (x : xs) = go x (allSame' xs)
```

Eta expansion then yields

```
allSame' [] acc = acc `seq` True
allSame' (x : xs) acc = go x (allSame' xs) acc
```

Inlining `go`,

```
allSame' [] acc = acc `seq` True
allSame' (x : xs) Nothing = allSame' xs (Just x)
allSame' (x : xs) (Just prev) =
  x == prev && allSame' xs (Just x)
```

Now GHC can recognize that the `Maybe` value is always `Just` on the recursive call, and use a worker-wrapper transformation to take advantage of this:

```
allSame' [] acc = acc `seq` True
allSame' (x : xs) Nothing = allSame'' xs x
allSame' (x : xs) (Just prev) = x == prev && allSame'' xs x

allSame'' [] prev = True
allSame'' (x : xs) prev = x == prev && allSame'' xs x
```

Remember now that

```
allSame xs = allSame' xs Nothing
```

and `allSame'` is no longer recursive, so it can be beta-reduced:

```
allSame [] = True
allSame (x : xs) = allSame'' xs x

allSame'' [] _ = True
allSame'' (x : xs) prev = x == prev && allSame'' xs x
```

So the higher-order code has turned into efficient recursive code with no extra allocation.

Compiling the module defining `allSame` using `-O2 -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all -dno-suppress-type-signatures` yields the following (I've cleaned it up a bit):

```
allSame :: forall a. Eq a => [a] -> Bool
allSame =
  \ (@ a) ($dEq_a :: Eq a) (xs0 :: [a]) ->
    let {
      equal :: a -> a -> Bool
      equal = == $dEq_a } in
    letrec {
      go :: [a] -> a -> Bool
      go =
        \ (xs :: [a]) (prev :: a) ->
          case xs of _ {
            [] -> True;
            : y ys ->
              case equal y prev of _ {
                False -> False;
                True -> go ys y
              }
          }; } in
    case xs0 of _ {
      [] -> True;
      : x xs -> go xs x
    }
```

As you can see, this is essentially the same as the result I described. The `equal = == $dEq_a` bit is where the equality method is extracted from the `Eq` dictionary and saved in a variable so it only needs to be extracted once.

---

What if list fusion *does* occur? Here's a reminder of the definition:

```
allSame xs = foldr go (`seq` True) xs Nothing where
  go x r Nothing = r (Just x)
  go x r (Just prev) = x == prev && r (Just x)
```

If we call `allSame (build g)`, the `foldr` will fuse with the `build` according to the rule `foldr c n (build g) = g c n`, yielding

```
allSame (build g) = g go (`seq` True) Nothing
```

That doesn't get us anywhere interesting unless `g` is known. So let's choose something simple:

```
replicate k0 a = build $ \c n ->
  let
    rep 0 = n
    rep k = a `c` rep (k - 1)
  in rep k0
```

So if `h = allSame (replicate k0 a)`, `h` becomes

```
let
  rep 0 = (`seq` True)
  rep k = go a (rep (k - 1))
in rep k0 Nothing
```

Eta expanding,

```
let
  rep 0 acc = acc `seq` True
  rep k acc = go a (rep (k - 1)) acc
in rep k0 Nothing
```

Inlining `go`,

```
let
  rep 0 acc = acc `seq` True
  rep k Nothing = rep (k - 1) (Just a)
  rep k (Just prev) = a == prev && rep (k - 1) (Just a)
in rep k0 Nothing
```

Again, GHC can see the recursive call is always `Just`, so

```
let
  rep 0 acc = acc `seq` True
  rep k Nothing = rep' (k - 1) a
  rep k (Just prev) = a == prev && rep' (k - 1) a
  rep' 0 _ = True
  rep' k prev = a == prev && rep' (k - 1) a
in rep k0 Nothing
```

Since `rep` is no longer recursive, GHC can reduce it:

```
let
  rep' 0 _ = True
  rep' k prev = a == prev && rep' (k - 1) a
in
  case k0 of
    0 -> True
    _ -> rep' (k - 1) a
```

As you can see, this can run with no allocation whatsoever! Obviously, it's a silly example, but something similar will happen in many more interesting cases. For example, if you write an `AllSameTest` module importing the `allSame` function and defining

```
foo :: Int -> Bool
foo n = allSame [0..n]
```

and compile it as described above, you'll get the following (not cleaned up).

```
$wfoo :: Int# -> Bool
$wfoo =
  \ (ww_s1bY :: Int#) ->
    case tagToEnum# (># 0 ww_s1bY) of _ {
      False ->
        letrec {
          $sgo_s1db :: Int# -> Int# -> Bool
          $sgo_s1db =
            \ (sc_s1d9 :: Int#) (sc1_s1da :: Int#) ->
              case tagToEnum# (==# sc_s1d9 sc1_s1da) of _ {
                False -> False;
                True ->
                  case tagToEnum# (==# sc_s1d9 ww_s1bY) of _ {
                    False -> $sgo_s1db (+# sc_s1d9 1) sc_s1d9;
                    True -> True
                  }
              }; } in
        case ww_s1bY of _ {
          __DEFAULT -> $sgo_s1db 1 0;
          0 -> True
        };
      True -> True
    }

foo :: Int -> Bool
foo =
  \ (w_s1bV :: Int) ->
    case w_s1bV of _ { I# ww1_s1bY -> $wfoo ww1_s1bY }
```

That may look disgusting, but you'll note that there are no `:` constructors anywhere, and that the `Int`s are all unboxed, so the function can run with zero allocation.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might just be implementing `find` and redoing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6123531/58668).  I think it's instructive, though, to see the innards of it.  (Note how the solution depends on equality being transitive, though note also how the *problem* requires equality to be transitive to be coherent.)

```
sameElement x:y:xs = if x /= y then Nothing else sameElement y:xs
sameElement [x] = Just x
allEqual [] = True
allEqual xs = isJust $ sameElement xs
```

I like how `sameElement` peeks at the first O(1) elements of the list, then either returns a result or recurses on some suffix of the list, in particular the tail.  I don't have anything smart to say about that structure, I just like it :-)

I think I do the same comparisons as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12846917/58668).  If instead I had recursed with `sameElement x:xs`, I would compare the head of the input list to each element like in solution 0.

Tangent: one could, if one wanted, report the two mismatching elements by replacing `Nothing` with `Left (x, y)` and `Just x` with `Right x` and `isJust` with `either (const False) (const True)`.

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is superior.

```
allSame [ ] = True
allSame (h:t) = aux h t

aux x1 [ ]                 = True
aux x1 (x2:xs) | x1==x2    = aux x2 xs 
               | otherwise = False
```

Given the transitivity of the (==) operator, assuming the instance of Eq is well implemented if you wish to assure the equality of a chain of expressions, eg a = b = c = d, you will only need to assure that a=b, b=c, c=d, and that d=a, Instead of the provided techniques above, eg a=b, a=c, a=d, b=c , b=d, c=d.

The solution I proposed grows linearly with the number of elements you wish to test were's the latter is quadratic even if you introduce constant factors in hopes of improving its efficiency.

It's also superior to the solution using group since you don't have to use length in the end.

You can also write it nicely in pointwise fashion but I won't bore you with such trivial details.

Comment: Could you add an explanation? Why is this implementation superior?

Comment: @O.O.Balance I just did. I hope it was helpful.

Comment: This is basically the same as solution #0 and solution #4, right, just expanded?

Answer (score -1):

While not very efficient (it will traverse the whole list even if the first two elements don't match), here's a cheeky solution:

```
import Data.List (group)

allTheSame :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allTheSame = (== 1) . length . group
```

Just for fun.

Comment: It might be fun but it's really bad. First, it doesn't work: `group` needs the elements to be sorted to work. Second, using length on the group result  means you have to count ALL the groups . Better pattern match on the list.

Comment: It *does* work: since you're only looking for the case in which there is one group, you don't need any sorting! And yeah, it's inefficient. I already said that.

Comment: My mistake. Still, it's doubly inefficient ,-)

Comment: `null . tail . group`, except it doesn't work on the empty list