# Check if two lists have the same elements in any order

Tags: list, haskell

In Haskell, how can you compare two lists to check if they are equal? Also the order shouldn't matter.

Example:

`[1,2] = [2,1]`

I tried `all (flip elem [1,2,3]) [2,1]`, but this returns `true`...

Comment: Did you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121256/efficiently-checking-that-all-the-elements-of-a-big-list-are-the-same

Comment: If the order shouldn't matter then you treat them as bags, which are multisets. There is a package that does the job, explained below.

Answer (score 14):

Something like this?

```
import Data.List (sort)
areEqual a b = sort a == sort b

OUTPUT:
*Main> areEqual [1,2] [2,1]
True
```

Comment: Is this the most efficient way?

Comment: @omega I have no idea. What kind and how big are the lists are you comparing?

Comment: @omega if you care about efficiency then you probably shouldn't be using lists in this way. `Data.Set` maybe?

Comment: I thinks for this type of data it does not get must better than this.

Answer (score 10):

As `Eq a => Eq [a]` (http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/libraries/base-4.5.0.0/Data-Eq.html)

you DON'T need extra code to compare lists for equality.

```
[1,2] == [2,1]
```

If you want to compare lists as bags, then a bag is a **MultiSet**, so look for a [Multiset package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/multiset/0.2.2/doc/html/Data-MultiSet.html)

```
import "multiset" Data.MultiSet as M

-- or

import "multiset" Data.IntMultiSet as M   -- if you deal with Ints 

M.fromList [1,2] == M.fromList [2,1]
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using PackageImports? More to the point, why are you doing so without mentioning it?

Answer (score 4):

A good data structure for "collection without order or repetitions" is from the module `Data.Set`:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

sameElems xs ys = S.fromList xs == S.fromList ys
```

This does, however, consider `[1,1]` to be equal to `[1]`, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Nice illustration of the use of inner's property of Data.Set. I've read that this could be done using this data container, but have no clue how to encode it, now I see. Thanks you.