# Haskell: Creating an isEqual function for a list

Tags: haskell

I want to create an isEqual function to compare the length of each string in a list. 
If each String is of equal size e.g. ["that", "there", "9999", " 1 #"]

return True if all strings are equal length
ELSE return False.

I'm looking for a way that requires the least amount of code and run time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [efficiently checking that all the elements of a (big) list are the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121256/efficiently-checking-that-all-the-elements-of-a-big-list-are-the-same)

Comment: Did you think really hard about it?

Comment: The first example compares strings by length, the second example compares integers by value. What should this function actually do?

Answer (score 2):

probably easier to write it recursively

```
isEq [] = True
isEq [x] = True
isEq (x:y:xs) = x==y && isEq (y:xs)
```

so short circuits with the first unequal size.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
minimumBy length == maximumBy length
```

(untested, and doesn't work for empty lists)

Answer (score 0):

There is always the one liner....

```
(== 1) . length . nub
```

You will need to import `Data.List`.  This will perform less well than pattern matching (barely so for lists smaller than 100), but it is easy to read, and probably fits the criteria "least amount of code".

Comment: I think he wants to apply `length` first, *then* remove duplicates. `(== 1) . nub . length`.

Comment: @chepner - he put both versions in the question.  In fact, I first did it locally with the extra length added, then took it out to match his `isEqual` function.  Note that your snippet won't work, since you need an extra map (for the list), and still need the lone length after the nub to be able to verify that the nubbed list is of length 1.

Comment: Oh, right. But his first question definitely wants to compare *lengths* of strings, not the strings themselves. So something like `(== 1) . nub . (map length)`?

Comment: @chepner - you still need the extra length....  The (== 1) is checking that the length of the post-nubbed list is 1.  Try `(== 1) . length . nub . map length`